# Print maximum one message daily

Tags: python, time

I have the following code.

I'd like to print a message if condition and print maximum one message daily (or other time interval)

```
time_interval = 86400
def print_message():
   ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
  while True:
    if not printed and (t <= t_max and t >= t_min):
      if (last message was printed in more than in a time_interval): #
        print_message()
    ...
    time.sleep(900)
```

I need to remember in the code when the last message was printed and that it is not more than a day from the present moment. If it is more than I day, condition # is fullfiled.

Comment: Don't [delete your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59707926/1324033) just to repost it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `datetime` for this:

```
import datetime

...

# interval is one day
INTERVAL = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
# set the 'last_printed' to one day ago, initially
last_printed = datetime.datetime.now() - INTERVAL

def do_thing_at_most_once_per_day():
    global last_printed
    # check the current time and see if it's been at least a day
    if datetime.datetime.now() - last_printed > INTERVAL:
        # at least one day has passed
        print_message()
        last_printed = datetime.datetime.now()
    else:
        # nothing happens
        pass
```

Keep in mind that, since this will all happen *within a single program*, that program must be kept running for it all to work. If you need to remember the last-printed time between different runs with the program, then you'll probably want to store the time in a file and use methods like `datetime.datetime.strptime()` and `datetime.datetime.strftime()` to read and write those.

[Here's the documentation for the `datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: But does it work when I change the interval e.g. to 20 seconds? That's because I used 86400 (day) seconds in a code.

Comment: You can change `INTERVAL` to whatever you want. 20 seconds would just be `datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)`